# I have a 'List' which contains all important files, how do I push the 'List' data to be always on top of the search result?

Tags: 2013, list, search, search-results

As above.

I have a 'List' which contains all important files, how do I push the 'List' data to be always on top of the search result?

When someone is using the search function, I want the search results to priortize and make sure the 'List' results are always on the top results.

*I am using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

Go to your search service application -> Authoritative Pages

Put here the link to your list.

[Manage relevance - Authoritative Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-authoritative-pages)